# Looping thru similar filenames with PHP file_exists

Tags: php, csv

I have a little web tool to cleanup CSV files.  The cleanup portion of the code is working smashingly, but I want to make this tool able to handle a user being able to keep the files on the system for some length of time and be able to upload/clean multiple files each day.  I'm using the date as part of the filename, so that handles keeping things unique for doing one file per day.  I am trying to have PHP loop thru checking for a filename with an _#.csv but I seem to be missing something.

Here is the code for the portion dealing with the filenames:

```
$date = date("Ymd");
$clean_outfile = $date . "clean_output.csv";
while(file_exists($clean_outfile)) {
if ($clean_outfile == ($date . "clean_output.csv")) {
    $clean_outfile = $date . "clean_outfile_1.csv";
    $cnt = 1;
} else {
    $cnt++;
    $clean_outfile = $date . "clean_outfile_" . $cnt . ".csv";
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: What's your question? Can you be more specific on the end result?

Comment: Try using absolute file paths with utilities like `getcwd()` or `__DIR__`. In my experience, different utilities (fopen and file_exists, for example) use different methods for relative file paths.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...

I had everything exactly right, but I forgot that I was generating the file in a different directory and I wasn't including the directory path in the file_exists test.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function. globe is like scandir that can work with regexp.